# Qt OpenGLScene working example

Tags: qt, opengl

I'm using an OpenGLScene as a wrapper of the openGL, and I've started with [the most simple example of that I've found on the internet](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qq/qq26-openglcanvas.html). I've just copied everything from the link where they have a zip.

I compiled and run the program, and apparently this warning is always coming up (in the drawbackground method):

```
if (painter->paintEngine()->type()
                != QPaintEngine::OpenGL) {
            qWarning("OpenGLScene: drawBackground needs a "
                     "QGLWidget to be set as viewport on the "
                     "graphics view");
            return;
```

Does anyone knows why (I'm on a Mac)? Does anyone has a more "stable" example? Is this warning relevant?

Basically, I would like to know why this warning is appearing, and how can I get rid of it...

I don't really know where to start. I've tried several simple things (making the QGLWidget current Context for instance), but I don't know enough Qt to understand the when and how is the drawbackground method called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Qt OpenGLScene working example

["Boxes"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-boxes.html) demo in Qt 4. Launch qtdemo, select demonstration->boxes. Or read it all [online](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/demos-boxes.html). Either that or read documentation for [overpainting](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-overpainting.html), [HelloGL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-hellogl.html) or any other [OpenGL example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-opengl.html).

> I'm trying to have a "wrapper" to OpenGL using Qt. Using Qt as GUI, and OpenGL as visualization

[QGLWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/QGLWidget.html)

Comment: So, what you are suggesting is that the standard approach should be to use QGLWidget? Because I want to put widgets on top of it, and GraphicsScene was what I found most appealing, as that example suggested.

Comment: Or you are suggesting putting the QGLWidget on the Scene, filling it and instead of drawing on the background, I draw on the QGLWidget? I don't see the advantage anyway...

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: "what you are suggesting" I'm suggesting to read the documentation. Standard approach is to draw whatever you want from within `QGLWidget::paintGL` when you want OpenGL acceleration. There's no "OpenGLScene" class in Qt framework.

Comment: ""On Mac OS X, when Qt is built with Cocoa support, a QGLWidget can't have any sibling widgets placed ontop of itself. This is due to limitations in the Cocoa API and is not supported by Apple."" from QGLWidget documentation... "OpenGLScene", as presented on the example I linked on the question is used to circumvent this limitation.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: "On Mac OS X, when Qt" I don't see how this is supposed to be related to your question - QGraphicItems are not widgets. Standard practice is to use QGLWidget. I suggest to try examples I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having `OpenGL` or `OpenGL2`?

Try this code

```
   if (painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL
   || painter->paintEngine()->type() != QPaintEngine::OpenGL2)
```

Comment: This will fail if the first is not found, use && instead

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do ?

IIRC the qq26 example didn't work in 4.7 (haven't tested it in 4.8).

But overpainting QWidgets on top of an openGL scene was added to 4.8 ( http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/opengl-overpainting.html ) rather than the hack in that example

edit: Just using an opengl display in Qt is simple, just derive from a [QWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qglwidget.html#details) and implement initializeGL, resizeGL and paintGL. There are Qt functions to wrap textures, VBOs, PBOs and all the other opengl stuff. See the [OpenGL examples](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/examples-opengl.html) in the distribution.

Comment: I'm trying to have a "wrapper" to OpenGL using Qt. Using Qt as GUI, and OpenGL as visualization.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - see edit, can't paste links in a comment. The example was for doing tricks to embed standard QtDialogs in opengl

Comment: Ok. So, when I'm saying I need Qt as GUI, I mention that I need to put Widgets on the scene. from what I've understood, one cannot put Widgets on QGLWidget and implement it that way. That is why I'm not considering the example as an hack... I need the scene to put widgets...

Comment: @J.C.Leitão - you can have an opengl scene in a QGLWidget and have all the normal app toolbars etc around it. If you want a QWidget directly in the opengl scene then see the box example in SigTerm's answer

Answer (score 0):

I've made a [small minimal OpenGL+Qt](https://sites.google.com/site/jorgecarleitao/code-reservoir/opengl) which I think can answer the point:

> I don't really know where to start. I've tried several simple things
>   (making the QGLWidget current Context for instance), but I don't know
>   enough Qt to understand the when and how is the drawbackground method
>   called.

I think it can help someone who was in the position I was when I asked this question.